# Send apns notification with big payload using apn_sender

Tags: ios, ruby, apple-push-notifications

My payload:

```
{
    :alert=>"hi",
    :badge=>1,
    :sound=>"default",
    :data => {
        :type=>2,
        :chat=>{
            :chat_room_id=>"54d9be6669702d0c15c00400",
            :anonymous=>false,
            :name=>"Benny Harel",
            :chat_item=>{
                :anonymous=>false,
                :icon=>"https://avatar.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/staging/person/avatar/54d885af69702d5ea74f0200/RackMultipart20150209-25749-1m4hy2k.jpg",
                :message=>"test",
                :timestamp=>1423561668
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not so big it is less than 2K so should be ok according to Apple documentation.
But it was not sent.

When I remove some data from it it works like a charm...

```
{
    :alert=>"hi",
    :badge=>1,
    :sound=>"default",
    :data=>{
        :type=>2,
        :chat=>{
            :chat_room_id=>"54d9be6669702d0c15c00400",
            :anonymous=>false,
            :name=>"Benny Harel",
            :chat_item=>{
                :anonymous=>false,
                :message=>"test",
                :timestamp=>1423561668
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What do I miss ?

Comment: It seems like this is issue in apn_sender https://github.com/arthurnn/apn_sender/issues/79.

Comment: You can check houston(https://github.com/nomad/Houston) gem. It worked for me.